# How to access and to change property value of a specific widget in a list

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

```
`List<Widget> _dataList = [
    DataCard(
      start: 0,
      end: 6,
    ),
    DataCard(
      start: 2,
      end: 8,
    ),
    DataCard(
      start: 4,
      end: 20,
    )
  ];`
```

`dataCard` is basically returns a `GestureDetector` widget with `Card` widget which shows the start and end values.

What I want to be able to do is to change the values of start / end after displaying the widgets on screen. How do I access the properties of any `dataCard` in the list?

This is the DataCard class:

```
class DataCard extends StatelessWidget {
  DataCard({this.start, this.end, this.key});
  final int start;
  final int end;
  final Key key;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print(key);
      },
      child: Card(
        key: key,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Start: $start',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'End: $end',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To visualize:
[image]

---

### For example, I want to change only the second `DataCard` widget's start and end values when I click the Floating Action Button. Is there a way to do that? Thank you!

### The end-goal is for users to be able to add a `DataCard` to the list wherein start and end values are also determined by them. Afterwards, the values of the `DataCard` are to be adjusted without user intervention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question connected to the big theme that called app state management.

Learn about it beginning from stateful widget, inherited widget, provider package, and BLoC pattern. (from simplest to hardest)

This is a video made by flutter team about stateful widget https://youtu.be/AqCMFXEmf3w.

going back to your question, simple example of using stateful widget:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var list = <List<int>>[
    [1, 6],
    [2, 8],
    [4, 20]
  ];

  void _incrementSecondCardStartParametr() {
    setState(() {
      list[1][0] += 1;
    });
  }

  Function decrementEndParametr(idx) =>  () => setState((){
      list[idx][1] -= 1;
    });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> _widgets = list
        .map((data) => DataCard(
              start: data[0],
              end: data[1],
              decrementEndParametr: decrementEndParametr(list.indexOf(data))
            ))
        .toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: _widgets),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementSecondCardStartParametr,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

    class DataCard extends StatelessWidget {
DataCard({this.start, this.end, this.key, this.decrementEndParametr});

final Function decrementEndParametr;
..
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: decrementEndParametr,
..
```

[image: qu]

Comment: I appreciate your answer, thanks! Will check out the topics you indicated and look for the answer there. 

With your example, so far, I have not found accessing properties of a widget (as in my example) as simple as "list[0][0]"

I'll redo my question to provide a more visual example.

Comment: I see. Separating the creation of data and the widget made the data accessible! Thank you for this. I may be able to complete my project now!